# Excel or Calc sum of columns

Tags: excel, calc

How can you apply a generic formula to add the sum of columns for ANY row?
I want to be able to apply one function that will work for all rows as opposed to manually typing A1....For example, A[current_row]+B[current_row]=sum;

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, what and why are you trying to do. The fastest way definetly will be just type `A1+B1` and copy formula down. Or `$A1+$B1` ifyou want to copy formula right, but sum the same columns.

Ifyou really really want to have current row,  you can use `INDIRECT`: formula `INDIRECT("A"&ROW(C1))` in cell C1 return value of cell `A1` Similar ōr B1, sum both, and done.